# fontspec+LuaTeX with Renderer=Basic causes some text to disappear, sometimes

Tags: luatex, fontspec, tufte

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Renderer=Basic]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}
rrrrrrvrrrrr

a-\emph{b}
\end{document}
```

When rendered using `lualatex`, the emphasized "b" does not appear; any text put after the "b" will also be suppressed.  If I change the `v` for an `r` in the first string, then the "b" appears.  Same thing if `Basic` is changed to `Node`.

**Question:** Is this a bug or a misuse of `fontspec`?

*Context:* This `setmainfont` appears in the default `tufte-book` configuration.
*Versions:* `This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022/Arch Linux)`, `fontspec 2022/01/15 2.8a`

Comment: `Basic` is documented as "a simplified mode useful only in a limited number of situations such as mathematics typesetting" which suggests that this is not expected use

Comment: Not really an answer, but you can use `Harfbuzz` renderer instead and get the intended result.

Comment: The Tufte classes seem more or less unmaintained at the moment, judging from the activity on the Github repository. Therefore probably the only solution is to solve the problem yourself by adding your own `\setmainfont` statement with a different rendered (and similar for sans and mono). You could still open an issue in the repository to let other people know about how you solved it, and maybe when the code gets maintained again this can be picked up by the developers.

Comment: open an issue at the luaotfload github.  even if node mode is better, basic mode imho shouldn't eat text.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; this is now at https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/241 .